# SQL Delete from with sub query error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Evening all, I have the following SQL Query for PDO:

`DELETE FROM group_members WHERE group_id IN( SELECT * FROM groups WHERE group_owner = 1 ) AND user_id = 2`

And for some strange reason I keep getting the following message:

`#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Now; I understand what the message means but I can clearly see that I've set a condition after the and so im not too sure what's going on.

Thanks for any help! :o) I'm sure its a noob mistake ;)

Comment: That was it! I knew it was something simple. Thanks for that. You should post that as a solution ;)

Comment: I'm on my iPad. It's too much effort to format code, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `*` in your subquery, you need to select the correct column:

```
SELECT group_id FROM groups WHERE group_owner = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM group_members
WHERE group_id
    IN ( SELECT group_id FROM groups WHERE group_owner = 1 )
  AND
    user_id = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you already have an answer, but also, consider using a join instead of the subquery:

```
DELETE gm.*
FROM group_members AS gm
JOIN groups g
  ON gm.group_id = g.id
WHERE gm.user_id = 2
  AND g.group_owner = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try-

```
DELETE FROM group_members WHERE user_id = 2 and group_id IN( SELECT * FROM groups WHERE group_owner = 1 )
```

I have not tested this and does not even know your desired result, but give this a try.